# Issues getting Microposts in Ruby on Rails to post to a followers wall

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, posting

I was following the Michael Hartl tutorial for creating a basic twitter type app, and I am trying to figure out how to get my posts to show up on a follower's wall rather than always posting to my own. After going through my code and various other answers, I believe the mistake lies with in the forms tags I set up inside of my HTML... Is there some very noticeable mistake? Or maybe a helpful tutorial on the topic that you know of?

```
       <div class="user-post">
        <%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
        <div>
            <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost...", class: 'create-post-input' %>
            <div>
            <%= f.submit "Post", class: 'post-button-light' %> 
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <div>
    <div class= "scrollBox" >
     <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
           <% @microposts.each do |micropost| %>
             <li>
              <%= micropost.content %>
              <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
                <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method: :delete %>
              <%end %>
             </li>
            <% end %>
      <%end%>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Controllers:

```
def show
 @micropost = current_user.microposts.build if signed_in?
 @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
def following
 @title = "Following"
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
 render 'show_follow'
end
def followers
 @title = "Followers"
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
 render 'show_follow'
end
```

Micropost controller:

```
  def create
   @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
   if @micropost.save
     redirect_to current_user
   else
     redirect_to current_user
   end
  end

  def destroy
   @micropost.destroy
   redirect_to current_user
  end

  private
   def micropost_params
   params.require(:micropost).permit(:content)
  end

  def correct_user
   @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
   redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
  end
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant action from your controller where you set the instance variables `@user` and `@microposts`. And how are your models associated? Basically how have you implemented the `follows` logic?

Comment: You are likely defining the `@microposts` as belonging to the logged in user rather than the user for the page you're viewing.

Comment: I updated to include the controllers and follows logic